# grab a value from a dict and insert in a new dict in Python

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries:

```
people = [
    {
    'name' : 'Ben',
    'par_one' : ['a','b','c'],
    'par_two' : [1,2,3,4,5]},
    {
    'name' : 'Jhon',
    'par_one' : ['x','c','g','z'],
    'par_two' : [3,6,9,]
}]

d2 = {
    'name' : 'Ben',
    'par_one' : 'random',
    'par_two' : 5
}
```

I need to modify the value of `d2` only if the value of `par_one` is "random", in this case, I want to overwrite "random" with the list in `people` that has the same key. The problem is that the list of people needs to have more dictionaries: so I have to find the correct dict (in the example case, the one with 'name' = 'Ben'), and then find the proper key and copy the value.

My expected output is:

```
final = {
    'name' : 'Ben',
    'par_one' : ['a','b','c'],
    'par_two' : 5
}
```

thanks a lot!!

Comment: Where is 'd1' ? and I think people[0]['name']=['Ben'] should be actually people[0]['name']='Ben'. Clarify these please before I give an answer.

Comment: sorry I did not change the name copynig from Phycharm.. i edit the question, thanks

Comment: Is `d2` just one dictionary among other dictionaries? Do you just need to do it for `d2` because that's just details of one person? If there are other dictionaries, where are they stored? Provide more context.

Comment: @AmalK there's no more context. I have `people` that can contain more dicts, but with the same structure. `d2` is a dictionary beacause I need to obtain this kind of output (also a json if you prefer) , but I just asked how to substitute the value of `d2` with the value of `people`. Imagine that that script is all you have.

Answer (score 1):

In the names are unique, you can build a second dictionary from people, to simplify the code.

```
dict_people = {x["name"]:x for x in people}
```

You can do the check:

```
final = d2
if d2["par_one"] == "random":
    name = d2["name"]
    final["par_one"]= dict_people[name]["par_one"]

print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you only need to change the '**par_one**' attribute.

```
if d2['par_one'] == 'random':
    selected_person = [person for person in people if person['name'] == d2['name']][0]
    d2['par_one'] = selected_person['par_one']
```

This will solve the problem!

What we are doing is getting the list of all people having the name **d2['name']** (e.g. '*Ben*'). Then we are selecting the 1st index of this list (Assuming that there will be one and only one person with this name).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final = d2.copy()

if final["par_one"] == "random":
    for item in people:
        if item["name"] == final["name"]:
            final["par_one"] = item["par_one"]
            break  # no need to continue

print(final)
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'Ben', 'par_one': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'par_two': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `d2` is rather a list of dictionaries rather than one dictionary. I'll call this list `input`.

```
def replace_key(people, input):
    for dct in input:
       if dct['par_one'] == 'random':
           for person in people:
              if person['name'] == dct['name']:
                   dct['par_one'] = person['par_one']
                   break
```

When the function exists, the argument you passed for `input` will contain the keys.
However, there is a thing that may really end up confusing you. `par_key` is a list. When you assign  `person['par_one']` to `dct[par_one]`, **YOU ARE NOT COPYING THE LIST**.
If you modified the list in one dictionary, it will also reflect in the other dictionary. This is because lists are references. If you truly want a copy which you have mentioned in your question, then instead of:

```
 dct['par_one'] = person['par_one']
```

do this:

```
 dct['par_one'] = person['par_one'][:]
```

or:

```
 dct['par_one'] = list(person['par_one'])
```

Also, this code modifies the dictionary by actually changing the values. If you want the results in a fresh dictionary without modifying `input`, do this:

```
def replace_key(people, input):
   final = input.copy()
    for dct in final:
       if dct['par_one'] == 'random':
           for person in people:
              if person['name'] == dct['name']:
                   dct['par_one'] = person['par_one'][:]
                   break
    return final
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more suggestion for you, without caring about which `key` is `'random'`.

```py
final = {}
for d2k in d2.keys():
     if d2[d2k] is 'random':
         for person in people:
             if person['name'] is d2['name']: 
                 final[d2k] = person[d2k]
                 break
     else:
         final[d2k] = d2[d2k]
```